# Redirect to https always with www optimization using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect everything to my domain to use https://www and below is the .htaccess I am currently using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It is working but it makes 2 redirects to the browser one if missing the www and the second if missing the secure which is slow of course and may be bad.

What I want or my question is can this be reduced to single redirect rule to make it add both the www and the https in one rule.

This online test tool shows 2 redirects https://varvy.com/tools/ :

```
Final status code: 200
2 Redirect(s)
http://domain.com
301 redirect
https://domain.com/
https://domain.com/
301 redirect
https://www.domain.com/
```

Any good optimizations to this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

2 rules but never more than one redirection

Comment: One rule does not work https without www: `https://domain.com/` should redirect to `https://www.domain.com/`.

Comment: My first rule do that. You add other rules before ? You should place these rules first

Comment: you were correct, I forgot `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` before the first rule. I removed it and worked as expected. Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use just 1 single rule

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

non-www to www redirect is not needed here because you want to redirect both versions to https://www .

**Clear your browser's cache before testing this.**

Comment: I do not want it hard coded for the domain, I need to more generic using %{HTTP_HOST} and %{REQUEST_URI} so I do not need to edit it for every domain.

Comment: Well, it's not possible with single redirection. %{HTTP_HOST} can be www or non www depending on the host name you type.

Comment: this also does not handle https on without www, it should redirect to `https://www`